# How to stack input fields after each other?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I have register site that have this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm3Fb.jpg, I want the input fields to stack after each other or pile up so appearance looks "good", is there a padding space reduction? or do I put something empty between the JLabel and JTextField so it increases the space, I tried to solve this problem by changing different layouts, however I did not achieve what I wanted

```
private JPanel SetUpRegister() {
        JLabel registerLabel = new JLabel("Registera");
        JLabel registerLabel1 = new JLabel("Login:");
        JLabel registerLabel2 = new JLabel("Password:");
        JLabel registerLabel3 = new JLabel("First Name:");
        JLabel registerLabel4 = new JLabel("Last Name:");
        JLabel registerLabel5 = new JLabel("Age:");
        JLabel registerLabel6 = new JLabel("Gender:");
        JLabel registerLabel7 = new JLabel("Bio:");
        registerLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        JButton createAccButton = new JButton("Create");
        backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(new BackRegisterListener());
        createAccButton.addActionListener(new CreateAccountListener());
        loginRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        passwordRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        fnRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        lnRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        ageRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        bioRegisterInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);

        String[] genderlist = { "Male", "Female", "Other" };
        registerList = new JComboBox<String>(genderlist);
        JPanel registerPanel = new JPanel();
        registerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(registerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel registerLabPanel = new JPanel();
        registerLabPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        registerLabPanel.add(registerLabel);

        JPanel usernamePanel = new JPanel();
        usernamePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        usernamePanel.add(registerLabel1);
        usernamePanel.add(loginRegisterInput);

        JPanel passwordPanel = new JPanel();
        passwordPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        passwordPanel.add(registerLabel2);
        passwordPanel.add(passwordRegisterInput);

        JPanel fnPanel = new JPanel();
        fnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        fnPanel.add(registerLabel3);
        fnPanel.add(fnRegisterInput);

        JPanel lnPanel = new JPanel();
        lnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        lnPanel.add(registerLabel4);
        lnPanel.add(lnRegisterInput);

        JPanel agePanel = new JPanel();
        agePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        agePanel.add(registerLabel5);
        agePanel.add(ageRegisterInput);

        JPanel genderPanel = new JPanel();
        genderPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        genderPanel.add(registerLabel6);
        genderPanel.add(registerList);

        JPanel bioPanel = new JPanel();
        bioPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bioPanel.add(registerLabel7);
        bioPanel.add(bioRegisterInput);

        JPanel buttonLoginPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonLoginPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonLoginPanel.add(createAccButton);
        buttonLoginPanel.add(backButton);


        registerPanel.add(registerLabel);
        registerPanel.add(usernamePanel);
        registerPanel.add(passwordPanel);
        registerPanel.add(fnPanel);
        registerPanel.add(lnPanel);
        registerPanel.add(agePanel);
        registerPanel.add(genderPanel);
        registerPanel.add(bioPanel);
        registerPanel.add(buttonLoginPanel);

        return registerPanel;

    }
```

Comment: A "good" layout is a tricky thing.  You seem to have started from a good place, using compounding layouts, but might consider using `GridBagLayout` instead of `BoxLayout`, but that's me

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.